# Mixture of string and number in enum?

Tags: c#

I have this Enum for my BlackJack game in C#. My game works except that how I show 2 instead of Two?

```
public enum Face
{
    A, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten,
    J, Q, K
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define the enum like the following:

```
 public enum Face
 {
    A=1, 
    Two, 
    Three, 
    Four, 
    Five, 
    Six, 
    Seven, 
    Eight, 
    Nine, 
    Ten,
    J, 
    Q, 
    K
 }
```

Then you can access the value as an integer using casting `(int)Face.J` will give you `11`, Please refer this working [Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wjae2Z)

**Please note:** You can assign integer values to enum, if not assigned then it will assume the first value as `0` `+1` will be added to succeeding items. That means if you use the code  `(int)Face.J` without assignment you will get the value as `10` instead for `11`

Comment: ya i know enum can have value start from value 0 for the first element. the thing is i have get that value done. what i need now is to display my enum value. If i can my version, only A, J, Q, K looks good. If I use enum value, 2-10 looks good. But I need to look good for the whole Face from A to K

Answer (score 2):

Create a dictionary of bindings:

```cs
public enum Face
{
    A, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, J, Q, K
}

public Dictionary<Face, string> cardValues = new Dictionary<Face, string> {
    [Face.A] = "A",
    [Face.Two] = "2",
    [Face.Three] = "3",
    ...
}

public string card = cardValues[Face.Two]; // "2"
```

Personally I'd just store the card value as an integer and use an array instead of the dictionary and enum.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the blackjack game with assignning values in a different class.

```
 class Card
 {
    //CREATE OUR RANK ENUM
    public enum SUIT
    {
        HEARTS,
        DIAMONDS,
        SPADES,
        CLUBS
    }


    public enum RANK
    {
        TWO , THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, 
        TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE
    }


    public SUIT MySuit { get; set; }
    public RANK MyRank { get; set; }

}
```

If the total value of the previous cards is less then 11, then the Ace value should be 11, otherwise 1

```
class Hand

{

    private List<Card> cards;


    public Hand()
    {
        cards = new List<Card>();
    }



    public void Clear()
    {
        cards.Clear();
    }


    public void Add(Card card)
    {
        cards.Add(card);
    }



    public void PopulateDeck()
    {
        foreach (Card.SUIT s in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Card.SUIT)))
        {
            foreach (Card.RANK r in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Card.RANK)))
            {

                cards.Add(new Card { MySuit = s, MyRank = r });
            }
        }

        Shuffle();
    } 


    public void Shuffle()
    {
        Random x = new Random();
        var shuffledcards = cards.OrderBy(a => x.Next()).ToList();


        foreach (Card c in shuffledcards)
        {
            cards.Add(c); 
        }
    }


    public Boolean Give(Card card, Hand otherHand)
    {
        if (!cards.Contains(card))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            cards.Remove(card);
            otherHand.Add(card);
            return true;
        }
    }//end method



    public void Deal(Hand hand, int perHand)
    {
        //deal to a single hand
        for (int i = 0; i < perHand; i++)
        {        
            if(cards.Count < 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No more cards to deal","",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else {
                this.Give(cards.ElementAt(0), hand);
            }
        }
    } //end method




    public Dictionary<String,int> GetCardRankSuit()
    {
        string cardSuit = "";
        string cardRank = "";
        string cardRanksuit = "";
        int rankValue = 0;
        int totalPoints = 0;

        Dictionary<String, int> rankList = new Dictionary<String, int>();
        //clears the collection of previous cards from previous games
        rankList.Clear();
        /*getting total points(any Aces by default will be 1)
         loop through our cards*/
        foreach (Card c in cards)
        {
            switch (c.MySuit)
            {
                case Card.SUIT.CLUBS:
                    cardSuit = "Clubs";
                    break;
                case Card.SUIT.DIAMONDS:
                    cardSuit = "Diamonds";
                    break;
                case Card.SUIT.HEARTS:
                    cardSuit = "Hearts";
                    break;
                case Card.SUIT.SPADES:
                    cardSuit = "Spades";
                    break;
            } //end switch
            switch (c.MyRank)
            {
                case Card.RANK.TWO:
                    rankValue = 2;
                    cardRank = "2 of ";
                    break;
                case Card.RANK.THREE:
                    rankValue = 3;
                    cardRank = "3 of ";
                    break;
                case Card.RANK.FOUR:
                    rankValue = 4;
                    cardRank = "4 of ";
                    break;
                case Card.RANK.FIVE:
                    rankValue = 5;
                    cardRank = "5 of ";
                    break;
                case Card.RANK.SIX:
                    rankValue = 6;
                    cardRank = "6 of ";
                    break;
                case Card.RANK.SEVEN:
                    rankValue = 7;
                    cardRank = "7 of ";
                    break;
                case Card.RANK.EIGHT:
                    rankValue = 8;
                    cardRank = "8 of ";
                    break;
                case Card.RANK.NINE:
                    rankValue = 9;
                    cardRank = "9 of ";
                    break;
                case Card.RANK.TEN:
                    rankValue = 10;
                    cardRank = "10 of ";
                    break;
                case Card.RANK.JACK:
                    rankValue = 10;
                    cardRank = "Jack of ";
                    break;
                case Card.RANK.QUEEN:
                    rankValue = 10;
                    cardRank = "Queen of ";
                    break;
                case Card.RANK.KING:
                    rankValue = 10;
                    cardRank = "King of ";
                    break;
                case Card.RANK.ACE:
                    if (totalPoints < 11)
                    {
                        rankValue = 11;
                        cardRank = "Ace of ";

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rankValue = 1;
                        cardRank = "Ace of ";
                    }

                    break;
            }
            totalPoints = totalPoints + rankValue;
            cardRanksuit = cardRank + cardSuit;
            rankList.Add(cardRanksuit, rankValue);
        }

        return rankList;
    } // end method




}//end class
```

In the form i use the dictionary string values for the filenames of the cards i want to display and get the corresponding values

```
     private void CreateControlsPlayer(String pictureName, int rankValueCard, Panel panel)
    {
        string folder = "Cards/";
        string fileExtension = ".png";

        //creates dynamically picturebox
        var newpictureBox = new PictureBox();
        newpictureBox.Width = 70;
        newpictureBox.Height = 130;
        newpictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        newpictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(folder + pictureName + fileExtension);
        newpictureBox.Location = new Point(xPlayer, 60);
        newpictureBox.Visible = true;
        newpictureBox.Name = "picBox" + "_" + xPlayer;

        xPlayer = xPlayer + 30;

        panel.Controls.Add(newpictureBox);

    }
```

then when i deal the cards i loop through the dictionary, player is a object of class hand

```
       private void btnDeal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   

        delear.Deal(player, 2);

        //gets the file paths of the pictures used to load images into picture boxes
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> entry in player.GetCardRankSuit())
        {
            CreateControlsPlayer(entry.Key, entry.Value, pnlPlayer);
        }


      }
```

not sure if it's efficient but just starting to take up programming again and creating a card game as excercise